# How to bind TreeView to ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, treeview, viewmodel

I have a view model as follows:

```
public class SolutionViewModel : TreeViewItemViewModel {

    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> Children {
        get { return mChildItems; }
    }

    public bool IsExpanded {
        get { return mIsExpanded; }
        set {
            if (value != mIsExpanded) {
                mIsExpanded = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }

            if (mIsExpanded && mParentItem != null)
                mParentItem.IsExpanded = true;

            if (this.HasDummyChild) {
                Children.Remove(EmptyItem);
                LoadChildren();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected {
        get { return mIsSelected; }
        set {
            if (value != mIsSelected) {
                mIsSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void LoadChildren() {
        var subFolders = default(ReadOnlyCollection<Folder>);
        if (!GetSubFolders(mSolution.Folder.Name, out subFolders)) {
            subFolders = new ReadOnlyCollection<Folder>(new List<Folder>());
        }

        foreach (var folder in subFolders) {
            Children.Add(new SolutionItemViewModel(this, folder));
        }

    }

    public string SolutionName {
        get { return mSolution.Name; }
    }

}
```

The .Xaml for the TreeView is as follows:

```
<TreeView Name="SolutionTree" ItemsSource="{Binding SolutionViewModel}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localmodels:SolutionViewModel}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="..\Resources\Folder_25x25.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SolutionName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

After a file is selected from `SolutionExplorer`:

```
    public void SetBindingContext(SolutionViewModel SolutionViewModel) {
        SolutionTree.DataContext = SolutionViewModel;
    }
```

This is a lazy loading model so that when the item is expanded, the children are loaded.

The problem is that I am not even getting the Solution Name as the top level node.

**Update:**
I verified that the model has `SolutionName` assigned:
[image]

In addition, per comment from @elgonzo, I edited the .Xaml to reflect a change to `ItemsSource` binding:

```
<TreeView Name="SolutionTree" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

**Update 2**
Code to assign the `TreeView` data context is executed when an event handler is raised after selecting a file from the `OpenFileDialog`:

```
private void OnOpenFile(string FilePath) {
    mSolutionManager = SolutionManager.Load(FilePath);
    mSolutionViewModel = new SolutionViewModel(mSolutionManager.Solution);
    mMainWindow.SolutionExplorer.SetBindingContext(mSolutionViewModel);
    mSolutionViewModel.Refresh();

}
```

When I step into the `Refresh()` method:

```
public void Refresh() {
    OnPropertyChanged("SolutionName");
}
```

...I find that the PropertyChangedEventHandler has no subscribers.

Comment: You need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface for your *SolutionViewModel* class, and fire the **PropertyChanged** event whenever the *SolutionName* property changes. I guess that *TreeViewItemViewModel* is also lacking an *INotifyPropertyChanged* implementation. Additionally, your TreeView seems to miss a DataTemplate for *TreeViewItemViewModel*...

Comment: `TreeViewItemViewModel` is an abstract class that provides implementation for `INotifyPropertyChanged`. By the time `SolutionViewModel` is assigned as the treeview data context, SoltuionName is assigned and does not change thereafter. I updated the question to reflect the inheritance chain descending from TreeViewItemViewModel.

Comment: Okay. Just about the SolutionName not showing. Either the property *SolutionViewModel* (used in the ItemsSource binding) is not set properly (or not firing an PropertyChanged event in case the binding is established before the property receives its intended value), or *SolutionName* (and thus *mSolution.Name*) is empty at the time the data binding is established. If *SolutionName* (i.e., *mSolution.Name*) is set after the data binding is established, the binding cannot know about that unless you inform it vie the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: If you set `SolutionTree.DataContext = SolutionViewModel;`, then the databinding `ItemsSource="{Binding SolutionViewModel}"` will try to bind to the property `DataContext.SolutionViewModel`, which would be equal to `SolutionViewModel.SolutionViewModel`. I guess you should try `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` to bind to the SolutionViewModel (i.e., DataContext).

Comment: I saw you did an edit about an hour ago. It looks like you didn't notice my last comment then, regarding trying to set the TreeView.ItemSource to `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` (for details, see my previous comment).

Comment: I did and made the change, but no difference in result. I even added a method to invoke the OnPropertyChanged event but there are no handlers subscribed to the event. After assigned the context, I call a refresh method on the view model. In TreeView, `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`

Comment: How often is SetBindingsContext called? Multiple times with the same SolutionViewModel object, perhaps? (check in the debugger with the help of a breakpoint). Also, what do you mean with "but there are no handlers subscribed to the event." in your last comment? The bindings will subscribe to the PropertyChanged event...

Comment: Only once - as a result of selecting a file (*.sln) from the `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: Well, i think you need to debug more thoroughly. You seem to suffer from some undesired side-effect, whatever it is. Or you made a mistake/oversight when debugging/troubleshooting (as unlikely as it may seem). Only more debugging and studying of your code and XAML will help you getting a handle on the problem. Unfortunately, with the information given here, i am unable to make any more reasonable guesses :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding to `ItemsSource` is wrong :

`<TreeView Name="SolutionTree" ItemsSource="{Binding SolutionViewModel}">`

`ItemSource` needs to be an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: ...or `DataContext = new List<SolutionViewModel>() {SolutionViewModel };`   ;)   I did this and it works.